# Entity Frameworks's Change Tracking detecting Decimal Precision difference after Mapping Client Object to Entity, And I don't want it to

Tags: c#, entity-framework, precision, change-tracking

I have a post method that takes change-set data from the client and updates the database accordingly based on the entities that are sent from the client.  I am trying to determine if the entity has changed, but am running into a problem.  After deserializing the object, I retrieve the Entity in question from the database and then Map the Client object to that Entity.  After this process I'm trying to use Entity Framework's Change tracking to see if the Entity has been modified, and it comes back Modified every time.  After some digging, I discovered that the client may be sending something like 1.000 and the db has it stored 1.0 even though the precision on the db is decimal(5,3).

Is there a way to tell Entity Framework's Change tracking to ignore precision only differences?

Here is my tracking code:

```
private bool HasSpanChanged(Span storeSpan, ChangeTracker tracker)
{
     var entries = tracker.Entries();
     if (entries.Any(x => x.Entity.GetType() == storeSpan.GetType() && ((Span)x.Entity).SpanId == 
       storeSpan.SpanId && x.State != EntityState.Unchanged))
          return true;
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer ended up being that how I was viewing the differences between the current and the original had actually transformed the data.  So Entity Framework was not looking at the precision differently. How I was outputting the data so I could read it during debug was the actual problem.  One of the values was truly being modified during the mapping, and therefore the EntityState was correct.

A cautionary tale on making sure your debugging code doesn't send you down a rabbit hole!